# JavaScript - Get Value of First Condition Met

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Wasn't quite sure how to title the question. Nonetheless - consider you have the following statement

```
if (messageOne || messageTwo || messageThree || messageFour) {
  // do something here ...
 }
```

How would you go about grabbing and using the message that gets met? For example

```
if (messageOne || messageTwo || messageThree || messageFour) {
  console.log(messageOne) // <-- but rather than hardcoding messageOne I want to be able to grab whichever one is executed
 }
```

Apologies if the question is poorly worded, can clarify if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use

```
let result = messageOne || messageTwo || messageThree || messageFour;
```

```js
let messageOne = null;
let messageTwo = null;
let messageThree = null;
let messageFour = "4";

let result = messageOne || messageTwo || messageThree || messageFour;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If it's not changing, you might as well use `const`

Comment: Thank you very much sir.